# Origin won't open the login screen PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, downloads, playonlinux

I have Ubuntu 14.04, and already downloaded Wine and PlayOnLinux. I am trying to open up Origin so I can dowload EA's Battlefront and play it.

I have tried it with Wine version `1.7.55`, `1.8-rc2-staging`, `1.6.2`, and few others, but none of them open up the Origin login. They just stay on the blue screen and I can't close the windows either. I'm using `OriginSetup.exe` (not the thin one) but I also have tried it with the latest download from Origins site `OriginThinSetup.exe`.

Both just get stuck on the blue screen! It's exasperating to the point where I'd almost rather just drop 100 on Windows 10. ALMOST... any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't rely on Wine, it is not 100% and what will work changes between releases, this game is really new, it is unlikely to work well. If you are going to spend £50 (or your equivalent) on a game, don't do it just for using on Wine, if you play alot of games on PC, Windows is really still the best option. :(

Comment: ok, any ideas where i could get a windows os pretty cheap? i coulndt find any sites that give student discounts (im a college student), but that may be cuz i dont know where to look

Comment: You can get any Windows ISO off Microsoft FOR FREE https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO and you get 30 days free, then you can extend that trial multiple times (just google extend windows trial), when the trial ends, Windows will still work but not update and some options are disabled, this will give you loads of time to play your game, with no piracy or expense :) Just skip license key on install.

Comment: Make a windows USB from Ubuntu : http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu

Comment: The games being designed for Windowz only is the problem... If you need to,y ou may be able to get a copy of windows through your institution discounted or for free via dreamspark or similar. Else if you do try with Wine and it doesn't work, report bugs with useful info on what happens (debug output etc) so it can be fixed/

Answer (score 1):

On [Wine appdb](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26175&iTestingId=89069), they say Origin works well but the installer has a bug, here is the workaround

> The workaround for installer:
>
> - Run the installer, wait until it'll finish installation, and actually throw an error about: the installer found some problems,
>   please download the installer from the link.
> - Don't download anything else, run VM or use friend's\any other's Windows PC.
> - Install Origin there
> - Make a full copy of Origin folder. (Default is: C:/Program Files (x86)/Origin)
> - Place the copy to winebox/playonlinuxdrive, overwriting any files exist.
> - Run the Origin.exe
> - Check that everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this too.  While I was waiting on the installer to throw the error, I was browsing the wine drives files.  I noticed that the Origin folder was read only, so I changed it in preparation for writing the folder in.  As soon as changed it, the Origin login popped up.  There was a correlation, but that does not denote causation.  :)